# Link to Sql Update Row

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

Ok i need to update field Active to True this is code

```
  public static bool FirstLogin(Guid ActivationCode)
    {

        using (InfinityNightDataContext data = new InfinityNightDataContext())
        {
           User user = data.Users.Single(User => User.EmailActivation == ActivationCode);


            if (user != null)
            {
             user.Active = true;
            user.Exp = "i HAs here";
            data.SubmitChanges();
               InstallMembershipCookie(user.UserId, user.Email, user.Password, user.UserType, user.FirstName, user.UserImg, "", true);

                return true;

            }
            else
            {

                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

and after **`data.SubmitChanges()`**; i can see the changes on the object user but not in **DataBase** in other function this works but in this case it's don't work ..

any one know what is the problem?

Comment: Are you sure that user is not null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible option (as you haven't said much about your setup): Are you using a local database, or a user instance, i.e. does your connection string contain AttachDbFileName? If so is there another copy of the database in your active bin folder (bin\debug, for instance)? If there is can you attach that to SQL express and see if your change has appeared?

Comment: i debuged sow yes user not null and i using local database and like i said i used the same metod but in Ajax WebMethod and there it works this function in the class .cs